# How to increment a stored json object without making repeat API calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest

I have an HTML page with text fields that I want to fill with data from a json object (received from an API call) upon initialisation. The json object is an array containing multiple records about different items.

I also have two buttons on my HTML page to cycle through the items, "previous" and "next" by incrementing the index value of the array and reflecting the data on the HTML page.

So far I am able to initialise my app by loading the item information held at index 0 in the json object:

```
var current = 0;

function displayItem(current) {
  var obj = "";
  $.get('http://xxxxxxxx/site/api/items/xxxxx', function (data) {
    obj = $.parseJSON(data);

    // I SHOULD MAKE THE NEXT/PREV BUTTONS ONLY MODIFY THE CODE 
    // BELOW, INSTEAD OF MAKING REPEAT CALLS TO THE API ABOVE:
    $("#info").html(obj.data[current].description);
    $("#itemID").val(obj.data[current].id);
    $("#price").val(obj.data[current].price);
    $("#picture").attr("src",obj.data[current].url);
  });
}

// HTML BUTTONS

this.nextItemButton = function () {
  current = current + 1;
  displayItem(current);
}

this.peviousItemButton = function () {
  current = current - 1;
  displayItem(current);
}
```

So what happens is that every time I click on the next or previous buttons on the HTML page, it is making repeat calls to the API, which seems inefficient (and probably straight up bad).

As I have already stored all the API data I need in the variable called "obj", there must be a way I can make the buttons change the index of the stored array without making a repeat API call.

I have tried making helper/callback functions for the code I have commented in the displayItem function, but every time I do it breaks the code and no items appear at all upon initialisation.

I guess it has something to do with the scope of the functions/nested functions or variables but I am getting nowhere!

Could someone please point me in the right direction!
Many thanks.

Comment: Is that copied and pasted? If so, you have a syntax error.

You are missing a quote and comma after yout http: url

Comment: Hey, i took out the real URL and just used a placeholder :) thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Just store obj globally. Using var inside displayItem function makes it local variable and limits its scope till the function execution completes .

```
var current = 0, obj;

function displayItem(current) {
    if(!obj){
        $.get('http://xxxxxxxx/site/api/items/xxxxx
        function (data) {
        obj = $.parseJSON(data);
     }

     // I SHOULD MAKE THE NEXT/PREV BUTTONS ONLY MODIFY THE CODE 
     // BELOW, INSTEAD OF MAKING REPEAT CALLS TO THE API ABOVE:
        $("#info").html(obj.data[current].description);
        $("#itemID").val(obj.data[current].id);
        $("#price").val(obj.data[current].price);
        $("#picture").attr("src",obj.data[current].url);
```

Comment: Ohhh Okay, that makes a tonne of sense. I'll try it out

Comment: This works perfectly, the problem is that the displayItem function does not initialise the app with the 0 index values anymore. I have to include the code for setting the html element info in both the IF and Else, is there a cleaner way to do it without duplicating code?

Comment: yaah, just remove the else check .

Answer (score 0):

The concept you're invoking is called *memoization*. In short, it means remembering the results of a function call so you don't have to do it again.

By separating your function into two separate concerns, that will make this a little easier. When the functions only do one thing, and are small, then adding this complexity is a bit easier:

```
var memo = [];
var current = 0;

function displayItem (current) {
  fetchItem(current, function (item) {
    // I SHOULD MAKE THE NEXT/PREV BUTTONS ONLY MODIFY THE CODE 
    // BELOW, INSTEAD OF MAKING REPEAT CALLS TO THE API ABOVE:
    $("#info").html(item.description);
    $("#itemID").val(item.id);
    $("#price").val(item.price);
    $("#picture").attr("src", item.url);
  });
}

function fetchItem (current, callback) {
  if (memo[current]) {
    callback(memo[current]);
  } else {
    $.get('http://xxxxxxxx/site/api/items/xxxxx', function (data) {
      var item = $.parseJSON(data);
      memo[current] = item;
      callback(item);
    });
  }
}

// HTML BUTTONS

this.nextItemButton = function () {
  current = current + 1;
  displayItem(current);
}

this.peviousItemButton = function () {
  current = current - 1;
  displayItem(current);
}
```

A word of caution, however. This code is vulnerable to a race condition. Suppose the user presses the "next" button twice, very quickly. The js will make two requests very quickly. The order in which the responses come back are not guaranteed. If the first request finishes after the second request, then the user will see item 1 displayed instead of item 2.